# javascript onsubmit not firing

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

I have a function that will not fire and I can't for the life of me figure out why. Hopefully someone can see what I'm missing...

in the page header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function confTakeIt(asdate,astime,aetime) {
    var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to signup for this OT?\n\n" + asdate + " " + $astime + " to " + $aetime);  
    if (ans) {
            return true;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
}
//-->
</script>
```

several different forms on the page calling the above function

```
<form method="post" name="takeIT" id="takeIT" action="takeOT.php" onsubmit="return confTakeIt('Sat 05-30-15','1530','0400')"><input type=hidden name="sumsg"><input type=hidden name="action" value="Add"><input type=hidden name="otid" value="61"><input type="image" src="/images/signup-sign.png" width=70 border=0 alt="Sign Up" value="submit"></form>

<form method="post" name="takeIT" id="takeIT" action="takeOT.php" onsubmit="return confTakeIt('Wed 06-03-15','1800','0630')"><input type=hidden name="sumsg"><input type=hidden name="action" value="Add"><input type=hidden name="otid" value="63"><input type="image" src="/images/signup-sign.png" width=70 border=0 alt="Sign Up" value="submit"></form>
```

Comment: [code]
function confTakeIt(asdate,astime,aetime) {
        var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to signup for this OT?\n\n" + asdate + " " + $astime + " to " + $aetime);  
        if (ans) {
                return true;
        } else {
                return false;
        }
    }
[/code]

Comment: did you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used wrong variable names

```
function confTakeIt(asdate, astime, aetime) {
    //variable names are astime and aetime not $astime and $aetime
    var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to signup for this OT?\n\n" + asdate + " " + astime + " to " + aetime);
    if (ans) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/79pr58zo/)

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `return` in `onsubmit` so it simply calls the `confTakeIt` function:

```
onsubmit="confTakeIt('Sat 05-30-15','1530','0400')"
```

Comment: can I do both of these:
function confTakeIt(asdate,astime,aetime) {
        var umsg = prompt("Special Message for Sgt about Shift?");
        document.takeIT.sumsg.value = umsg;

        var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to signup for this OT?\n\n" + asdate + " " + astime + " to " + aetime);
        if (ans) {
                return true;
        } else {
                return false;
        }
}

Comment: yes. but it [may not be the best strategy](http://alistapart.com/article/neveruseawarning)

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it like this:

just simply return the value of `ans`,also remove `$`signs

```
function confTakeIt(asdate,astime,aetime) {
    var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to signup for this OT?\n\n" + asdate + " " + astime + " to " + aetime);  
    return ans; //[OK] returns 'true' otherwise 'false'
}
```